# Java Validator unique constraint on a List

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

Let's say I have

```
@ValidLibrary
class Library {
    @Valid
    List<Book> books;
}

class Book {
    @Unique
    String title;
}
```

I want to have a validator that checks the books in `Library` are all unique by their `title`. I can do a custom validation as such:

```
public class UniqueListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueList, List<Book> books> {
    public boolean isValid(List<Book> books, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // Use books to determine duplicates    
        // if invalid, find the index in the List
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("title already exists")
            .addPropertyNode("title")
            .inIterable().atIndex(index)
            .addConstraintViolation();

        return false;
    }
}
```

And use `@UniqueList` on the property of `List<Book> books` on `Library` class, but the issue here is that the `ConstraintViolation` violation I get back is on `Library`, and there is no easy way to convert that node to `Book`.

Any better solutions?